# Aiogram Webhook

Tags: python, aiogram, webhook

пытаюсь поставить вебхук на бота, используя библиотеку AIOGRAM (c
pytelegrambotapi всё ок), использую вот эту доку

https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/webhook_example.html

Пытаюсь подвязать, ничего не выходит, пишет:

```
aiohttp.http_exceptions.BadStatusLine: 400, message="Bad status line 'Invalid method encountered'"
```

Вот мой код:

```
import os
from time import sleep

from aiogram.utils.executor import start_webhook

from src import config
from src.bot.initialization import bot, logger, TOKEN, dp
from src.bot.webhook.util import get_ip, generate_selfsigned_cert

WEBHOOK_PORT = 8443                                                     # 443, 80, 88 или 8443 (порт должен быть открыт!)
ip = get_ip()

logger.debug(f'Текущий айпи - {ip}')

WEBHOOK_HOST = f'https://{ip}:{WEBHOOK_PORT}'                           # айпи сервера
WEBHOOK_PATH = f'/webhook/{TOKEN}'
WEBHOOK_URL = f'{WEBHOOK_HOST}{WEBHOOK_PATH}'

logger.debug(f'Вебхук урл - {WEBHOOK_URL}')


WEBAPP_HOST = '0.0.0.0'
WEBAPP_PORT = os.getenv('PORT', default=WEBHOOK_PORT)


WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT = config.CERTIFICATE_PEM_PATH       # Путь к сертификату
WEBHOOK_SSL_PRIV = config.KEY_PEM_PATH               # Путь к приватному ключу


generate_selfsigned_cert(hostname=ip)


async def on_startup(dp):
    logger.info('Запускаюсь')
    await bot.set_webhook(WEBHOOK_URL,
                          certificate=WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT,
                          drop_pending_updates=True)


async def on_shutdown(dp):
    logger.info('Выключаюсь...')

    await bot.delete_webhook()

    await dp.storage.close()
    await dp.storage.wait_closed()

    logger.info('Пока!)')


def start_server():
    start_webhook(
        dispatcher=dp,
        webhook_path=WEBHOOK_PATH,
        skip_updates=True,
        on_startup=on_startup,
        on_shutdown=on_shutdown,
        host=WEBAPP_HOST,
        port=WEBAPP_PORT,
    )
```

У меня нет домена на сервере, посему я обращаюсь к нему через апишник и порт, всё поднимаю через докер, порты открыты и путь есть, но консоль выдает надпись выше, а если пройти по getwebhookifo телеграмма, то там пишет что ссл неверный, но у меня работало и с этой ошибкой, да и если бы он действительно был неверный, оно бы не прокидывало каждое сообщение боту, а так консоль обычно вот такая, когда я пишу какое-то сообщение боту:

```
bot-cur_dir-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
bot-cur_dir-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/web_protocol.py", line 334, in data_received
bot-cur_dir-1  |     messages, upgraded, tail = self._request_parser.feed_data(data)
bot-cur_dir-1  |   File "aiohttp/_http_parser.pyx", line 551, in aiohttp._http_parser.HttpParser.feed_data
bot-cur_dir-1  | aiohttp.http_exceptions.BadStatusLine: 400, message="Bad status line 'Invalid method encountered'"
```

Я не работал с AIOHTTP, и учитывая то, как просто без всяких проблем разворачивается подключение к вебхуку, думал что там под капотом всё окей, но как оказывается нет, посему прошу помощи у гуру данного форума и библиотек aiohttp и aiogram.
Спасибо за внимание и будущую помощь

Answer (score 0):

```
import logging

from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.contrib.middlewares.logging import LoggingMiddleware
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.dispatcher.webhook import SendMessage
from aiogram.utils.executor import start_webhook



API_TOKEN = ''

# webhook settings
WEBHOOK_HOST = 'ngrok'
WEBHOOK_PATH = '' # тут оставь пустым
WEBHOOK_URL = f"{WEBHOOK_HOST}{WEBHOOK_PATH}"

# webserver settings
WEBAPP_HOST = 'localhost'  # or ip
WEBAPP_PORT = 5000

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
dp.middleware.setup(LoggingMiddleware())


@dp.message_handler(text='/start')
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    # Regular request
    # await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
    # or reply INTO webhook
    await message.answer('Привет')
    # return SendMessage(message.chat.id, 'Привет')


async def on_startup(dp):
    await bot.set_webhook(WEBHOOK_URL)
    # insert code here to run it after start


async def on_shutdown(dp):
    logging.warning('Shutting down..')

    # insert code here to run it before shutdown

    # Remove webhook (not acceptable in some cases)
    await bot.delete_webhook()

    # Close DB connection (if used)
    await dp.storage.close()
    await dp.storage.wait_closed()

    logging.warning('Bye!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_webhook(
        dispatcher=dp,
        webhook_path=WEBHOOK_PATH,
        on_startup=on_startup,
        on_shutdown=on_shutdown,
        skip_updates=True,
        host=WEBAPP_HOST,
        port=WEBAPP_PORT,
    )
```

Вот так у меня работает

Comment: Я вместо токена вставил свой токен, в вебхук хост вставил адрес сервера, в вебапп - 0.0.0.0 и порт 8443, всё равно ничего, запускаться запускается, проверка токена через сайт выдает такое   "ok": true,
  "result": {
    "url": "my_address",
    "has_custom_certificate": false,
    "pending_update_count": 2,
    "last_error_date": 1673861810,
    "last_error_message": "Connection refused",
    "max_connections": 40,
    "ip_address": "my_address"
  }

При этом, порт на который идет запрос открыт, я через ufw проверил, всё ок должно быть

Comment: а WEBHOOK_HOST какой url ты поставил, ты пользуешься ngrok

Comment: Нет, у меня свой сервер, его айпи я туда и сунул